# Select only most recent record

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a  MariaDB table

```
calldate timestamp,
channel  varchar(30)
```

Values are:

```
2019-12-01 SIP/91953838-084ec34
2019-12-02 SIP/91953838-023ec35
2019-12-03 SIP/91953839-03e4523
2019-12-04 SIP/91953839-0365hee
```

How to select only most recent record for each  channel?

So i need result as:

```
2019-12-02 SIP/91953838
2019-12-04 SIP/91953839
```

'91953838' or '91953839' are actually channel numbers (about 50 unique values)  whereas '084ec34' just system code assigned to each calls randomly so there is no two records like  that:

```
    2019-12-01 SIP/91953838-084ec34
    2019-12-02 SIP/91953838-084ec34
```

Table contains 10+ millions rows, so i need most effective query.
Mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB,

Comment: `SELECT channel, MAX(calldate) calldate FROM my_table GROUP BY channel;` Next.

Comment: @Strawberry Check the data again, your query would return every record in the table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the OP wants a better answer, perhaps they can ask a better question. (In this instance, the correct answer is, of course, normalisation)

Comment: "i need most effective query" - With the current schema you will have to read the entire table (full scan). You should split the `channel` column. Then you can write a query which only needs to read 50 instead of all 10M rows.

Comment: Paul , You're right but this is table which a telephone system has created and uses. I could'n redesign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(channel, '-', 1) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT timestamp, channel
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If your version of MySQL/MariaDB does not support `ROW_NUMBER`, then we have to do more work:

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.channel
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(channel, '-', 1) AS channel, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(channel, '-', 1)
) t2
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.channel, '-', 1) = t2.channel AND
       t1.timestamp = t2.max_timestamp;
```

Comment: Tim , i get :ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS 
My version is Mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB

Comment: Maybe you're using an earlier version of MariaDB.  Try my alternative query which I have added.